# Slack byte in structures in C

Tags: c, struct, structure

What is meant by a slack byte in structures in C?

Answer (score 11):

Usually padding bytes to ensure that data is aligned correctly. For example:

```
struct x {
    int a;     // four bytes
    char b;    // one byte
               // three bytes slack
    int c;     // four bytes
} xx;
```

will probably have slack bytes between `b` and `c` to get `c` aligned on a correct boundary.

You can check this by seeing what `sizeif(xx)` gives you (12 in the case above although it depends on the implementation).

Some architectures run slower if they have to use (for example) a four byte value that isn't aligned on a four-byte boundary. *Some* architectures won't allow that at *all*, instead generating an exception.

Comment: y only between b & c, y not between a & b. and as int is 2 bytes and char 1 byte, how much slack byte is of size.

Comment: @mohit, probably not between a and b since char most likely can be aligned on a 1-byte boundary. If the int was two bytes, there would probably only be 1 byte of slack after b.

Comment: one more doubt, is slack byte always present in structures, or it is some special cases.

Comment: **Most** architectures won't allow it at all. The exception just happens to be the most common architecture, x86.

Comment: @mohit, the only case where there are no padding bytes is when the elements of your structure naturally align. Most good programmers designing structures that will be used as part of a library API (where you have to worry about compatibility between versions, etc.) will take care that the structure is naturally aligned. Microsoft is notorious for not having done so and instead using nonstandard 'pack' directives to the compiler to force it to generate misaligned structure elements.

Answer (score 2):

```
struct student 
{
     char a;//it takes 8 byte
     char b;
     char c;
     char d;
     int e;
};

struct student1;
{
     char a;
     int b;
     char c;//it takes 12 byte(suppose sizeof(int)=4;
}
```

---

student is treated as:

```
____________________
|char|char|char|char|   // one byte for each char so there is no slack=4byte
|____|____|____|____|
____________________
|int |  * | *  |*   |   // int takes for byte;=4byte total space is 4+4=8;
|____|____|____|____|
```

---

and student1 is treated as:

```
____________________
|char| s  |s   | s  |   // one byte for char
|____|____|____|____|   // s indicates a slack byte..=4byte
____________________
|int |*   |*   |*   |   //int takes four bytes;=4byte
|____|____|____|____|
 ___________________
|char| s  |s   | s  |   // one byte for char
|____|____|____|____|   // s indicates a slack byte..=4byte
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please review [The Code Formatting Guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code). Thank You :-)